# Create a list of Connected Clients using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here are 2 related questions. Posting them together makes more sense.

**Question 1**

I have a node.js app which emits an event out to all clients, and all current clients will respond with a `ready` emit. How can I create a list of all the clients that replied to the initial emit, and what kind of identification can be used to distinguish the clients?

**Question2:**

What I am trying to do after  collect a list of connected clients, is to then access a MySQL database table of `N` number of rows and assign each client `X` rows each. These rows will be emitted back to their respective clients. How can this be done?

**Current Code for Qn 1**

**Node Code**

```
setInterval(function() {
    util.log('Checking for new jobs...');
    dbCheckQueue(function(results) {  // checks if there are new rows to "distribute" to clients
        if (results.length) {
            util.log(results.length + ' new jobs found.');
            io.sockets.emit('job_available');
        }
    });
}, 10*1000);
```

**Client-side JS Code**

```
socket.on('job_available', function() {
                console.log('Job Available.. Responding with Ready!');
                socket.emit('ready');
            });

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function() {
        // UPDATE N rows with client_id in column checkout.
        // Then SELECTS * from table where checkout = client_id
        getListings(client_id, function(listings) {
            socket.emit('job', listings);   // send jobs
        });
    });
});
```

**Current Code for Qn 2**
*The code works for a single client, but how do I loop through all connected clients and perform the same updating of column and selecting of rows?*

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function() {
        // UPDATE N rows with client_id in column checkout.
        // Then SELECTS * from table where checkout = client_id
        getListings(client_id, function(listings) {
            socket.emit('job', listings);   // send jobs
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to keep track of the connected clients yourself. The simple way to do that would be to use an array:

```
var clients = [];

io.sockets.on('connect', function(client) {
    clients.push(client); 

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(client), 1);
    });
});
```

Then you can references that `clients` array on the server wherever you need to, in your `ready` event handler or whatever. Something like:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function() {
        // UPDATE N rows with client_id in column checkout.
        // Then SELECTS * from table where checkout = client_id
        clients.forEach(function(client, index) {
            var client_id = index; // Just use the index in the clients array for now
            getListings(client_id, function(listings) {
                socket.emit('job', listings);   // send jobs
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: could you proevide the logic of a getListings() function, because I applying smiliar solution but I see on screen on the name of a first logged user.

Comment: The `getListings` call is just sample code that I pulled from the original question. I have no idea what it contains or how it's implemented.

Comment: I see, because I am storing clients in array and when I try to retrieve them with the hepl of `foreach` or `for` loops I just only the the first logged in client's username in browser.

Answer (score 20):

Socket.io provides you with a public api for that, so instead of hacking something up like Bryan suggest you can use:

```
io.sockets.clients()
```

That will returns an array of all connected clients.

If you want all clients connected to a certain namespace:

```
io.of('/namespace').clients()
```

But you can even filter it even more.. if you want to have all sockets in a room:

```
io.sockets.clients('room name here as first argument')
```

Will return a array of connected sockets for the room `room name here as first argument`

Comment: Thanks 3rdEden, I used Bryan's solution with slight modifications because I only want those connected clients that replied with a `ready` message to be pushed into an array. Can using the API do something that in a different way?

Comment: Actually slightly hacking with the api would be better all you had to do was something like   socket.isReady = true; when is ready is recieved and by that you would of saved yourself from mantaining another list :P

Comment: @3rdEden You are the author of node-memcached? I am using it well :)

Comment: Yes, I'm also the author of that module :-)

Comment: I believe the functionality in this answer is deprecated in 1.0

Comment: @web-student-ksu what is the current solution for this use case in v1.0+?