# socket.io socket.set and socket.get - what is the callback argument for?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just want to attach some variables to my sockets, but I don't understand the .get and .set methods. They both have a third argument for a callback. Can this be omitted? What is it for?! Does the callback itself intherit arguments?

My best guess is that it's there for when socket.io isn't using memory store but is saving this stuff somewhere else and needs an error checking callback.

```
socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
    socket.set('nickname', name, function (arguments) {
      doSomethingMysterious();
    });
```

I'm using socket.io 0.9.x

The function is defined in socket.js

```
/**
 * Stores data for the client.
 *
 * @api public
 */

Socket.prototype.set = function (key, value, fn) {
  this.store.set(key, value, fn);
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`set` and `get` are asynchronous. The callback will be called when these operations are completed. You can omit it, or you can use it for whatever purpose you like, not just error handling.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that they're asynchronous makes it easier to wrap my head around the whole thing. 

In common cases would this be used to save values to a db somewhere and then use another emit back to the client to let them know it's saved? I guess it's still not clear to me, other than namespace collision, why we couldn't just use something like `socket.property=value;` 

Just started with node.js 2 days ago, please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: Yeah, a good reason why you would use `set`, `get` (as oposed to just saving a value in an object), is to save it in the db. In fact `socket.io` seems to already have a build in `redis store`, but I'm not a socket.io user so I can't really say how this can be used. If you look at the source code, when calling `set` this puts the value in the `store`: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L246

Comment: and that .store by default is redis?  Or is it like just in place so you can set up your own store?

Comment: @Funkodebat no, the default is actually the MemoryStore, you'll have to configure to use the redis store. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Answer (score 35):

The `get` and `set` functions on the socket object [were removed in version 1.x](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/commit/b6a48996898a5cc4112373e91e56d4d1afc46cdf). The proper way to store and retrieve values now is through properties on the socket object, like so:

```
socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
  socket.nickname = name;
});
```

As seen on the [example code from the official repo.](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js#L35-L36)

Comment: Where this will be stored? Will this be delivered to the client or stored only server-side?