# Modify socket.name with a custom name when the socket ID is generated

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm just trying to send custom data from the client side to the server, without add more request.

I was reading the thread:  [socket.io socket.set and socket.get - what is the callback argument for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360110/socket-io-socket-set-and-socket-get-what-is-the-callback-argument-for) 
and says: [The get and set functions on the socket object were removed in version 1.x](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/commit/b6a48996898a5cc4112373e91e56d4d1afc46cdf).

I'm using a very simple node/express application, with the next code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected: ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log( socket.name + ' has disconnected from the chat.' + socket.id);
    });
});
```

Exist a way to set a custom value in the property `socket.name` when the socket is initializated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works only if you don't need have your application in cluster or run in other servers.

```
var clients = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected: ' + socket.id);

    clients[socket.id] = {name: 'Your name'};

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log( clients[socket.id].name + ' has disconnected from the chat.' + socket.id);
        delete clients[socket.id]; //Delete client
    });
});
```

After, you will can find the data related on this way:

```
clients[socket.id];
```