# Make a new prop in socket io object and get undefined using react.js as client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I was trying to store data into a socket prop that I can reference it later. However, on others socket.on it comes out as undefined

Here is the code:

```
var userlist = ['Dang Huy','Alice','Bui Sam', 'Hai Hai'];
var onlineUser = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
socket.on('userOnline', (data) => { //User Alice go in
    if(userlist.includes(data)){ 
      onlineUser.push(data); 
      io.sockets.emit('onlineUser', onlineUser);
    }
socket.user_name = data; // store data into user_name
console.log(socket.user_name + ' is online');  //logout Alice is online
})

socket.on('userSendMessage', (data) => {
    console.log(socket.user_name) // socket.user_name is undefined here!!
    console.log(data) // still log out the message from the client side

    io.sockets.emit('serverSendMessage', 'Hello')
  })

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    onlineUser.splice(onlineUser.indexOf(socket.user_name), 1)
    io.sockets.emit('onlineUser', onlineUser)
  })

})
```

Comment: I think this is a `scope` problem, you are defining the `socket.user_name`, but actually at internals js creating a separate scope for the socket, so you can put there where you want it will not be shareable between other event listeners, sharing such things will create race conditions so it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by next event (could you provides an example?)Oh I notice something very wrong , you won't never go to some event and that is purely normal, your socket scope variable is into `{}` & you ask it out of them, just move the listeners up:

```
var userlist = ['Dang Huy','Alice','Bui Sam', 'Hai Hai'];
var onlineUser = [];


io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('userOnline', (data) => { //User Alice go in
    if(userlist.includes(data)){ 
      onlineUser.push(data); 
      io.sockets.emit('onlineUser', onlineUser);
    }
    socket.user_name = data; // store data into user_name
    console.log(socket.user_name + ' is online');  //logout Alice is online
  })
  socket.on('userSendMessage', (data) => {
    console.log(socket.user_name) // socket.user_name is undefined here!!
    console.log(data) // still log out the message from the client side

    io.sockets.emit('serverSendMessage', 'Hello')
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    onlineUser.splice(onlineUser.indexOf(socket.user_name), 1)
    io.sockets.emit('onlineUser', onlineUser)
  })
})
```

Comment: by mean event. I meant any the next socket.on('userSendMessage'). 2nd I put it in socket object that will store data. So the scope with in io.on(...) should work right ?...i have a project that I do that and work perfectly fine but the project that i am working on is not working.
p/s: check out this repo on index.js https://github.com/hokakede1/chatApp .. it works perfectly fine

Comment: In you repo yes you did put all you listener in the `io.on()`That is what you need to do here as my answer said

Comment: i did, there are closing bracket for io.on() at the last line.

Comment: Ok so could you tell at which line you got undefined ?? do you speak about the data variable?

Comment: i commented on that line. socket.user_name in socket.on('userSendMessage')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360110/socket-io-socket-set-and-socket-get-what-is-the-callback-argument-for. This one has the way that i am trying to do in the answer of 32 votes

Comment: I do not see the problem here, could you provides the full code ? if it's open source

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself. The Problem was: I was using Reactjs as front-end framework, so each component has different socket session, therefore socket.username is defined if I call socket.emit('userSendMessage') in that same component that I connected to. If I socket.emit('userSendMessage') in other component, It will return undefined because of different session of each component.