# How to update socket object for all clients in room? (socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.object = socket.id;

    socket.on('updateObject', function(data) {
        // How to update socket.object here for all clients?
    });
});
```

How to do it?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563885/socket-io-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-connected-sockets-clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please note that this function is not available anymore in socket.io versions higher then 1.0, it is recommended to keep a array of your socket.id's so you can iterate over them if need be. [example by ynos1234](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028902/1531822)**

You can achieve this with the `forEach` function:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.object = socket.id;

    socket.on('updateObject', function(data) {
        io.sockets.clients('room').forEach(function (socket, data) {
            // goes through all clients in room 'room' and lets you update their socket objects
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I added an answer below for Socket.IO versions 1.0 and above.

Answer (score 23):

**For the users using Socket.IO versions 1.0 or above this is the updated code for doing so.**

Code to update socket object for all clients in a room

```
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Room Name'].sockets;   

//to get the number of clients
var numClients = (typeof clients !== 'undefined') ? Object.keys(clients).length : 0;

for (var clientId in clients ) {

     //this is the socket of each client in the room.
     var clientSocket = io.sockets.connected[clientId];

     //you can do whatever you need with this
     clientSocket.emit('new event', "Updates");

}
```

Comment: The API has changed again. To access the array of clients for a particular room, use `clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Room Name'].sockets`.

Comment: to emit to a single room you can use : `io.to('roomName').emit('event, 'msg'); `

Comment: Can anyone point the API's documentation at https://socket.io/docs/server-api/? I am unable to find. Thanks

Comment: Somehow this also doesn't work for me. It always returns the error, `Cannot read property 'rooms' of undefined` any help?