# How to check socket is alive (connected) in socket.io with multiple nodes and socket.io-redis

Tags: node.js, nginx, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I am using socket.io with multiple nodes, socket.io-redis and nginx. I follow this guide: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

I am trying to do: At a function (server site), I want to query by socketid that this socket is connected or disconnect

I tried `io.of('namespace').connected[socketid]`, it only work for current process ( it mean that it can check for current process only).

Anyone can help me? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I have the same usecase.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I check socket is alive (connected) with socketid I tried
>   namespace.connected[socketid], it only work for current process.

As you said, separate process means that the sockets are only registered on the process that they first connected to. You need to use [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis) to **connect all your nodes** together, and what you can do is **broadcast an event** each time a client connects/disconnects, so that each node has an updated real-time list of all the clients.

Comment: Hi, I mean I want to check socket is connected or not with socketid. it not mean check socket is connected or not.
your approach can not solve 2 problem:
1. I have socketid, I want to check there are socket is connected or not?
2.The event connect and disconnect will fire asynchronously. maybe actually It connect first and disconnect later, but on server,because of many reasons the disconnect  event fire first and connect later. So actually it is disconnect but on server store it connected

Comment: Please update your comment as I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Each node **should not** have all the socketIds but it's okay if **one node** queries all the nodes with a socketId to see if it's there. Just add a layer of communication between your nodes if you really want to query by socketid.

Comment: I am trying to do:
At a function on 1 node, I want to query by socketid that this socket is connected or disconnect.
It's not easy to make a layer of communication between nodes by the way sent a message to all of nodes and get return value to check socket is connected or disconnect. you can reference at http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#sending-messages-from-the-outside-world

Comment: If posible, you can give me snippet code, on idea, it's easy but actually it's so difficult
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303635/1502019)

as mentioned above you should use socket.io-redis to get it work on multiple nodes.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Comment: I am using it (socket.io-redis), I think you don't understand my question. I am trying to do: At a function on 1 node (server side), I want to query by socketid that this socket is connected or disconnect

Comment: everything is right. socket.io is using sessions by default which is not shared throw multiple app instances.  Shared memory will do the trick ( redis, mongodb, any storage... ). socket.io-redis that's only interface to interact with redis.
make sure you configured the same prefix. try out any redis GUI to watch and test it locally ( also you can get any information by socket id directly from redis storage )

Comment: If posible, you can give me snippet code. Tried for long time but not success

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and no solution at my convenience. So I made a log of the client to see the different methods and variable that I can use. there is the `client.conn.readystate` property for the state of the connection "open/closed" and the `client.onclose()` function to capture the closing of the connection.

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
let clients = [];
io.on('connection', (client)=>{
    clients.push(client);
    console.log(client.conn.readyState);
    client.onclose = ()=>{
        // do something
        console.log(client.conn.readyState);
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(client),1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Socket.IO application on a multi-nodes cluster, that means multiple SocketIO servers, there are two things to take care of:

**Using the Redis adapter**  and **Enabling the sticky session feature:** when a request comes from a SocketIO client (browser) to your app, it gets associated with a particular session-id, these requests must be kept connecting with the same process (Pod in Kubernetes) that originated their ids.

you can learn more about this from this Medium story (source code available) [https://saphidev.medium.com/socketio-redis...](https://saphidev.medium.com/socketio-redis-at-a-scalable-gke-cluster-with-github-workflows-844318f80ce)